# Converting an unmanaged package to a managed package

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package

My organization has been developing a new app in Salesforce for internal use. After a period of internal testing, we would like to begin selling this app. Currently, our app is an unmanaged package developed in an enterprise version of Salesforce, however we will need to convert to a managed package in order to sell it.

How difficult is it to convert an unmanaged package to a managed package? We would like to avoid starting over from the beginning in a developer edition. My development team currently seems to be under the impression that this is what we would have to do.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a managed package is just as easy as creating an unmanaged package. The only requirement to create a managed package is that you’re using a Developer Edition organization.

You can follow below steps.

1. signup for a new developer organzation.
2. Create unmanaged package from your current org.
3. Install that package in your developer organization created in step 1
4. Define a namespace for your organization.
5. From Setup, enter Packages in the Quick Find box, then select Packages.
6. Edit the package that you want to make managed, then select Managed.

As you said you are planning to sell it then you need License Management Application (LMA) in another org to manage your license.

You can follow Salesforce documentation for futher details after completing above steps

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=enabling_managed_packages.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

It's important that you determine your packaging and licensing environment soon. If you haven't signed up for the ISV program, that is where to start.

Once you are a registered ISV, you can use your Partner Business Org's Environment Hub to create a new Partner Developer Org. That org will become your release org. In that org, deploy all your code (using a metadata tool like Eclipse, or by just installing your unmanaged package). Make sure that all tests pass, and then add it to a new *managed* package.

Creating the managed package is the easiest part. Much harder is joining the ISV program, getting your AppExchange Listing, and passing security review.

The ISVForce workbook is a great resource on all this. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/